# Adiabatic Invariant in Variable Mass Oscillator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, adiabatic

Suppose you have an harmonic oscillator whose mass is adiabatically changing such that $T\frac{dm}{dt}\ll m$ where $T$ is the period of the motion. It could for example be an ice ball slowly melting connected to a spring.
Considering the adiabatic invariant $\frac{E}{\omega}$ where $E$ is the energy of the oscillator and $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$, the energy of the oscillator should increase. However I can't figure out why this happens by starting from first principles (like Newton equations). How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of motion for " ice ball slowly melting connected to a spring"

you start with the kinetic energy $T_c$

$$T_c=\frac 12 m(\tau)\,\dot x^2$$

and the potential energy of the spring $U$

$$U=\frac 12 k\,x^2$$

with Euler- Lagrange you obtain the EOM.

$$ \begin {array}{c} m \left( \tau \right) {\ddot x}+kx+ \left( {
\frac {d}{d\tau}}m \left( \tau \right)  \right) {\dot x}\end {array}
 =0
$$

you can make this Ansatz for $m(\tau)$

$$m(\tau)=m_{{0}}\,{{e}^{-{\frac {\tau}{T}}}}$$

where $T$ is the time constant $~[s]$ for the ice melting process and $m_0$ is the initial ice  mass

the EOM is now

$$\ddot x+\underbrace{\frac{e^{(\tau/T)}\,k}{m_0}}\,x-\frac{1}{T}\,\dot x$$

**Edit**

The total energy is:

$$E=\frac 12\,m_{{0}}{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\tau}{T}}}}{{\dot x}}^{2}+\frac 12\,k{x}^{2}$$

with :

$$T=\frac {2\pi}{\omega}=\frac{2\,\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{m_0}}}~,k=m_0\,\omega^2$$

$$E=\frac 12\,m_{{0}}{{\rm e}^{-\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\,\sqrt {{\frac {k}{m_{{0}}}}}\tau}}{{\dot x}}^{2}+\frac 12\,m_{{0}}{\omega}^{2}{x}^{2}
$$

for $\tau \mapsto \infty$

$$E=\frac 12\,m_{{0}}{\omega}^{2}{x}^{2}
~,\frac{E}{\omega}=\frac 12\,m_0\,\omega\,x^2=\text{const.}$$

Comment: But how does this yield the fact that, for example, when the mass will be halved the energy will be multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$ (according to the adiabatic invariance of $\frac{E}{\omega}$?

Comment: I can't answer this equation, perhaps you need another ansatz for $m(\tau)$ ?

Comment: If you take $T\mapsto \infty$ you get you obtain your result

Comment: Thanks, but: when you get the equation of motion, I am not quite sure that the $\dot{x}$ term should be there, as the relative velocity between the ball and the released mass is zero. Also, why did you take $T$ as being equal to the initial period? And finally: I think there is a typo in your second to last inequality: shouldn't it be $\sqrt{k}$ in place of $k$?

Comment: the $\dot x$ term came from the variable mass term, the idea to use T equal to the period came to me later this way I use „edit“ , I corrected the last equation